# Usage of "to keep" vs. "to preserve"

Tags: expressions, verbs, word-usage

I'm writing a computer program that allows the user to alter some parameters while ensuring that the combination of the parameters stays constant.
For example: it calculates a + b = c. If the users increase a, the program has to decrease b accordingly to make sure c doesn't change.
The target audience of my program is nontechnical, especially artists.
Should I write "Keep c" or "Preserve c"?

Comment: I'd say that it "ensures that C remains consistent".

Answer (score 4):

I think preserve is the correct choice.

To me, the usage of 'keep' would indicate that you are storing the value of 'C' and that it is independent of any other values.

However, in this instance C is dependent on other values. Therefore you're changing the value of B to preserve the desired value of C.

Answer (score 0):

Following the endless knowledge of Microsoft Paint, which **maintain[s the] aspect ratio** when resizing a picture I suggest **maintain c**.

> **maintain** Keep (something) at the same level or rate [(ODO)](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/maintain)